# Droid Explorer only shows the "/" directory, and that's empty

Tags: rooting, root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, droid-explorer

I have an RCA Voyager tablet (Android 6.0.1) plugged into my computer with USB debugging and everything. I launched Droid Explorer and am following this guide for rooting (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2684210 - method 1). For whatever reason, having it in recovery mode doesn't show up under Ubuntu, and all I got from Ubuntu once was a "Failed to mount Android." Anyway a comment suggested this app, but it isn't showing any files. I just freshly installed this and all of Android Studio last night, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After opening the console it showed me a message telling me I had to install busybox. After installing [busybox from here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en) the file browser worked.